# AWS Fifo Halts on Lambda Throttle

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs, throttling

We use a [Fifo Queue](https://aws.amazon.com/sqs/) configured with a [Lambda Function](https://aws.amazon.com/lambda/) as a [processor](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/new-for-aws-lambda-sqs-fifo-as-an-event-source/). We use [MessageGoupId](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/using-messagegroupid-property.html) and [BatchSize](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/API_CreateEventSourceMapping.html#SSS-CreateEventSourceMapping-request-BatchSize) to optimistically remove redundant messages. To rate limit processing we use [reserved concurrency](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/configuration-concurrency.html). Our function [timeout](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/) has to be high. The queue [maximum receives](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/amazon-sqs-new-dead-letter-queue/#:%7E:text=Maximum%20Receives%20%E2%80%93%20The%20maximum%20number,to%20the%20Dead%20Letter%20Queue.) is set to ten.

## Observed

When there are a lot of messages in the queue, the Lambda function scales up. Once it scales enough to throttle, the queue processing comes to a complete hold and no further messages are processed until some minutes have passed.

I’m assuming this is because of throttling, because halting always coincides with throttling and when increasing the reserved concurrency, it takes much longer for the processing to come to a halt.

I’m assuming the time until the queue starts up again has to do with the lambda [retry limit](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2019/11/aws-lambda-supports-max-retry-attempts-event-age-asynchronous-invocations/#:%7E:text=the%20event%20age.-,Maximum%20Retry%20Attempts,with%20fewer%20or%20no%20retries.), the function [timeout](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2018/10/aws-lambda-supports-functions-that-can-run-up-to-15-minutes/) and the queue [visibility timeout](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/sqs-visibility-timeout.html). But since I don’t know exactly what happens this is a guess.

## Issue

There are no errors logged and ultimately all messages are processed, but since processing is time and throughput sensitive, it is not acceptable to have the queue halt for many minutes.

## Questions

What is happening and how can we solve this? If more information is needed I’d be very happy to debug further.

---

*Edit:* Found this: `To allow your function time to process each batch of records, set the source queue's visibility timeout to at least 6 times the timeout that you configure on your function. The extra time allows for Lambda to retry if your function execution is throttled while your function is processing a previous batch.` and we are certainly in violation, but I'm not sure how / if this explains the observed behaviour.

Comment: hard to guess without detail understanding of your system and scaling algorithms. Maybe in some moment lambda don't delete (or return in queue) a processed message? If at least one message has status `in flight` you can't read other messages.

Comment: @rzlvmp Would this be caused by throttled messages though? I've been reading https://data.solita.fi/lessons-learned-from-combining-sqs-and-lambda-in-a-data-project/ and it sounds like it might be the culprit (even though it's complaining about DLQ, not about delays). Note that we are not seeing any lambda errors.

Comment: @rzlvmp I've created Minimal, Reproducible Example and was able to solve my problem (see answer below). This seems to be expected AWS behaviour and happens due to a misconfiguration. So not an issue in our code logic itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## How to Reproduce

At the end of this answer there is a complete, minimal example that is written to easily reproduce the issue.

To deploy, create all files and fill in your aws `profile` and desired `region` into all `sh` files.

Then run

> . deploy-stack.sh

to create the cloudformation stack that contains all necessary resources.

Then open the AWS web interface (SQS) and run

> . generate-messages.sh

to generate messages on the queue.

One can then see that about half of the messages are processed before the function throttles and the queue comes to a complete halt.

To remove the cloudformation stack after all debugging has been completed run `remove-stack.sh`

## Solution

AWS documentation [contains a note](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-queueconfig) saying

> To allow your function time to process each batch of records, set the source queue's visibility timeout to at least 6 times the timeout that you configure on your function. The extra time allows for Lambda to retry if your function execution is throttled while your function is processing a previous batch.

Changing the `timeout` on the lambda function from `600` to `100` and redeploying the stack allows all messages to process correctly even though the lambda function throttles.

I can not explain why this behaviour is observed and would greatly appreciate feedback on that. However the above does solve the issue described.

## Files

`stack.yaml`

```yaml
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Description: Debug Stack for Fifo with Lambda Processor
Resources:
  MyLambdaRole:
    Type: AWS::IAM::Role
    Properties:
      RoleName:
        Fn::Sub: lambda-role
      AssumeRolePolicyDocument:
        Version: 2012-10-17
        Statement:
          - Action:
              - sts:AssumeRole
            Effect: Allow
            Principal:
              Service:
                - lambda.amazonaws.com
      ManagedPolicyArns:
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AWSLambdaExecute
        - arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonSqsFullAccess
      Path: /
  MySqsQueue:
      Type: 'AWS::SQS::Queue'
      Properties:
        FifoQueue: true
        VisibilityTimeout: 600
  MySQSQueueFunction:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::Function
    Properties:
      Handler: index.handler
      Role: !GetAtt MyLambdaRole.Arn
      Runtime: nodejs12.x
      Timeout: 600
      ReservedConcurrentExecutions: 5
      Code:
        ZipFile: |
          exports.handler = (event, context) => new Promise((resolve) => {
            setTimeout(resolve, 1000);
          });
  MySQSLambdaEventSource:
    Type: AWS::Lambda::EventSourceMapping
    Properties:
      BatchSize: 1
      Enabled: false
      EventSourceArn: !GetAtt MySqsQueue.Arn
      FunctionName: !Ref MySQSQueueFunction
Outputs:
  QueueUrl:
    Value:
      Ref: MySqsQueue
  EventSource:
    Value:
      Ref: MySQSLambdaEventSource
```

`deploy-stack.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

profile=local
region=us-east-1

# -----------------

aws cloudformation deploy \
--profile $profile \
--region $region \
--template-file stack.yaml \
--stack-name fifo-lambda-debug \
--capabilities CAPABILITY_NAMED_IAM
```

`generate-messages.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

profile=local
region=us-east-1

# -----------------

function genGroupId {
  echo $(shuf -i 1-10 -n 1)
}
function genRndStr {
  echo $(openssl rand -hex 12)
}
function entry {
  echo "{\"Id\":\"$(genRndStr)\",\"MessageBody\":\"$(genRndStr)\",\"MessageGroupId\":\"$(genGroupId)\",\"MessageDeduplicationId\":\"$(genRndStr)\"}"
}

# -----------------

echo "Getting Subscription UUID..."
eventSource=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
--query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='EventSource'].OutputValue" \
--output text \
--profile $profile \
--region $region \
--stack-name fifo-lambda-debug)

echo "Getting Queue Url..."
queueUrl=$(aws cloudformation describe-stacks \
--query "Stacks[0].Outputs[?OutputKey=='QueueUrl'].OutputValue" \
--output text \
--profile $profile \
--region $region \
--stack-name fifo-lambda-debug)

echo "Disabling Subscription"
aws lambda update-event-source-mapping \
--profile $profile \
--region $region \
--uuid $eventSource \
--no-enabled \
> /dev/null

while : ; do
    echo "Waiting until Subscription disabled..."
    [[ $(aws lambda get-event-source-mapping \
      --profile $profile \
      --region $region \
      --uuid $eventSource \
      --query "State") != '"Disabled"' ]] || break
    sleep 10
done

echo "Queueing Messages..."
for i in {1..30}
do
  aws sqs send-message-batch \
  --profile $profile \
  --region $region \
  --queue-url "$queueUrl" \
  --entries "[$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry),$(entry)]" \
  > /dev/null
  echo "Done: $i / 30"
done

echo "Re-Enabling Subscription..."
aws lambda update-event-source-mapping \
--profile $profile \
--region $region \
--uuid $eventSource \
--enabled \
> /dev/null
```

`remove-stack.sh`

```sh
#!/bin/bash

profile=local
region=us-east-1

# -----------------

aws cloudformation delete-stack \
--profile $profile \
--region $region \
--stack-name fifo-lambda-debug
```

Comment: sorry, don't have a time to run all this stuff, but in my quick opinion suspicious place is `VisibilityTimeout: 600`. You have only 10 minutes to over task processing. And lambda timeout is `600` too. So in some moment by some reason lambda late with processing message in 600 seconds and it returns to queue. Starting from this moment messages returning to queue, processing late, returning to queue, processing again, ... Also you have `setTimeout(resolve, 1000)` in code, so if my understanding is correct, you need at least 1 second to resolve one event. So throughput is 60 events/m?

Comment: (1) Yes, the visibility timeout is the culprit here. And I agree that it could be a problem in some cases, but I still don't see how it actually causes the observed behaviour (2) No, because we use the groupId the throughput is much, much higher. For the `generate-messages.sh` here it is 60 * 10 / minute